# Strange Tab control default colours in 2 apps on same monitor

Tags: vb.net, tabcontrol

I have 2 small apps, both employ a tab control. All display properties seem to be identical on the tab controls, but when displayed on the same monitor, one displays in a brighter colour, making the controls (labels, Text boxes, etc) appear messy. Both apps look ok on the development PC, but on the users PC there is a noticable difference. Anyone got a reason why, and more importantly a solution?
The Apps are written in VB.Net
Thanks in advance for your help
Paul

Answer (score 0):

We have a CRM Application on my enterprise using Firebrick background color.

It never displays the same color depending on the monitor. See that every monitor
have different display panels and different gamma values.

Are they running the same Graphic Card Model? nvidia, ati. The output display is not only given by the monitor. The graphic card is involved as well.

Comment: Thanks for the rapid response.I have come across this 'entertaining' display problem too. This one is different in that both apps are on the same PC, displayed on the same monitor, side by side. They should exhibit the same colours too. I am thinking that there is something strange in the background code (eg, form setup). Any idea where to start looking.

Comment: Are they running the same Graphic Card Model? nvidia, ati. The output display is not only given by the monitor. The graphic card is involved as well ;)

Comment: Is there somewhere in the VB.net environment where I can check this out? I haven't knowingly altered any Graphic card parameters.
Thanks for your patience.